# Where do I put my app's privacy policy and when do I display it?

Tags: ios-appstore

I  am going to submit my first iOS app in the next few days and I am a little unsure about what to do with the privacy policy. Is it enough just to have it on the App Store page or do I need to include it in the app? Do I need to display it to the users from within the app before the register for an account? Finding it hard to find any information on this.

Answer (score 1):

Having a link to the privacy policy in the relevant field in iTunes Connect has been sufficient for me in the past. Obviously having a link in the app may allow users to find it more easily, however just the link in iTunes Connect seems sufficient based solely from personal experience.

> **Privacy Policy URL (optional)**
>
> A URL that links to your company’s privacy policy. Privacy policy URLs are required for all apps that offer auto-renewable or free subscriptions and for apps that are set to Made for Kids. Customers see this URL on their invoice and on the subscription confirmation email they receive. The URL can specify a localized site.
>
> Include the entire URL, including the protocol.
>
> Note that if your app is set to Made for Kids, you need to specify a Privacy policy URL for each localization provided for the app.

<sup>Source: [iTunes Connect App Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html)</sup>

Comment: So I need to host the privacy policy on a website or can it just be from within the app store page?

Comment: @keXmEX Oh, are you talking about including the privacy policy in the app's description on the App Store? This is definitely a no-no: iTunes Connect provides a separate field where you should provide a link to the privacy policy page for the app.

Comment: So I should  host it on a webpage?

Comment: @keXmEX Yes, I've added a relevant quote and page link from Apple's developer guide to my answer.

Comment: Where would you recommend to host a page? I suppose some free services would be ok.

Comment: @kelin If you've already got a website, [this is a natural place to put it](https://georgegarside.com/meta/privacy-policy/). If not, but your project is open source, your repository host may offer web hosting, such as [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com) which is free. I can't recommend anything outside of these two options personally.